# Code for setting Arduino Nano PWM Timer 1 at 10 bit and 16 kHz

Tags: arduino, pwm

Can anyone provide me with code for setting an Arduino Nano's timer1 to 10-bit, 16kHz PWM and also to 10-bit, 20kHz, including the body for a timer-interrupt? I wish to test it in both settings.

But, first of all, is it feasible to set a Nano's PWM timer1 (interrupt) to 10-bit, 16kHz or even 9-bit, 16kHz PWM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds like a hardware question. Fortunately, there's an Arduino forum. ;)

Comment: There's also an [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)